# How to rewrite the regression coefficients to form an equation?R

Tags: r

```r
test<-lm(spreadsheet[,1]~spreadsheet[,2])
test<-test[1][[1]]
> test
(Intercept) spreadsheet[, 2] 
  359.6182526432944  -2.475447990866698
```

how to write the coefficients of a regression in order to form an equation? So that it is possible to isolate "x". Expected output:

K= 359.6182526432944  -2.475447990866698 *x

x= -(17249403*K-6203200166)/42700000

I tried using expression function but it didn't work:

```
> eq<- expression(test[1][[1]]*x)
> eq
expression(test[1][[1]] * x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the coefficients of your linear model object like this

```
b <- test$coefficients[1]  ### intercept
k <- test$coefficients[2]  ### slope
```

so

```
eq <- expression(b + k*x)
```